# How do I efficiently map transformations over a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

a bit of a funny ask.

I have a (big) table that looks like:

| transaction_date (index) | store_id | department_id | gross_revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '2020-01-01' | Store1 | Fruit | $7.50 |
| '2020-01-01' | Store2 | Fruit | $2.75 |
| '2020-01-01' | Store1 | Veg | $47.50 |
| '2020-01-01' | Store2 | Veg | $8.25 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

And I want to transform the `gross_revenue` column depending on the value of `store_id` and `department_id`.

For argument sake, let's say I want to increase all `Store1` sales by 25%, increase `Veg` sales by 10%, and `Fruit` sales by 75% (let's not worry about the order just yet).

I'd like the user to be able to write:

```
modifiers = {
    'store_id': {
        'Store1': lambda x: x*1.25
     },
    'department_id: {
        'Veg' : lambda x: x*1.10, 
        'Fruit': lambda x: x*1.75
    }
}
```

Is there a performant way to execute this in Pandas?

As a baseline, this code works:

```
from functools import reduce

ans = (table
 .assign(gross_revenue = lambda x: x
     .apply(lambda row: reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), [row['gross_revenue'], 
                                                   modifiers.get(row['business_id'], lambda x: x),
                                                   modifiers.get(row['department_description'], lambda x: x)
                                                  ]), axis=1)
    )
)
```

However, it takes close to 2min (table is 5-10m rows).

Does anyone know a faster approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many transformations do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
store_adjust = {'Store1': 1.25, 'Store10':1.3}
dep_adjust = {'Veg': 1.10, 'Fruit':1.75}

df['gross_revenue'] *= ( df['store_id'].map(store_adjust).fillna(1) *
                         df['department_id'].map(dep_adjust).fillna(1) )
```